# get ArrayList JSP variables in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, arraylist

I am trying to get familiar with javaScript and currently stumbled upon one issue:
How to get ArrayList JSP variables in JavaScript function?

Fo example I figured out how I can get an int value, but dont know how to move the array list

```
var total='<%=counter%>'; //convert jsp to JavaScript
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to convert an ArrayList to javascript array, you can loop through the ArrayList and add each element to javascript array. try this

**javascript:**

```
var jsArray = [];
<%for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){%>
    jsArray.push("<%= arrayList.get(i)%>");
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript array and create the array using values from the server

```
var myArray=new Array("Value1","Value2","Value3");//condensed array
var myArray=["Value1","Value2","Value3"];//literal array
```

You can also use the JSON format to get the literal from the server.